# CoreLocation Delegate functions do not run until view controller viewDidLoad function is finished

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

This is more than likely something very easy to solve but I've been at it for some time and can't seem to get at an answer.

I would like to know why a Delegate method for `CLLocationManager` does not trigger until after the `ViewDidLoad` function when the `CLLocationManager` is loaded within the `ViewDidLoad` function.

I have set my default region to Sydney Australia within my App Scheme and I have encapsulated my locationManager within its own class as follows:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

/* Class location is a class to track user location and return a location object. */
class usrLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    //MARK: Properties
    var locationMgr: CLLocationManager!
    var location: CLLocation!
    var seenError: Bool = false

    //MARK: Public Methods

    func startTracking() {
        locationMgr = CLLocationManager()
        locationMgr.delegate = self
        locationMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationMgr.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    //Return a location object
    func getLocation() -> CLLocation {
        locationMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
        return location!
    }

    //MARK: CLLocationManagerDelegate
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        locationMgr.stopUpdatingLocation()

        if (seenError == false) {
            seenError = true
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        location = (locations ).last
        locationMgr.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

I have initialised the class in my `ViewController` and try to begin tracking my current location in `viewDidLoad`.

The code looks like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var location = usrLocation()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Track location 
    location.startTracking()
    location.getLocation()

    //update Label text
    sLongitude.text = "\(location.getLocation().coordinate.longitude)"
    sLatitude.text = "\(location.getLocation().coordinate.latitude)"    
}
```

`getLocation()` never returns location as it is always nil as the delegate `didUpdateLocations` function does not run. Why is this?

Comment: Please read the documentation for the `CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation()` method.

Comment: @maddy, thanks I went back and reread the documentation for `CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation()` but it still doesn't solve my problem as to why the delegate isn't called while in the viewControllers viewDidLoad() method. The documentation says the delegate should run immediately as soon as startUpdatingLocation() is called. Maybe I'm just taking the wrong approach here? I am a complete Swift novice so it wouldn't surprise me if this is the case.

Comment: This is not an answer so I won't mark it as such but I've found an explanation on another post for why CoreLocation delegate doesn't load. [Location not updating before the view loads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585909/location-not-updating-before-the-view-loads).   So I will try building this in with an Activity spinner which stops once the startUpdatingLocation() function triggers the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get this working using a completion handler but couldn't so my solution has been to ignore setting the label text via viewDidLoad and to instead update the labels once the location variable has been set. That way viewDidLoad completes, the delegate gets called and the labels get updated.

```
var location: CLLocation! {

didSet {
    //update Label text
    sLongitude.text = "\(location.getLocation().coordinate.longitude)"
    sLatitude.text = "\(location.getLocation().coordinate.latitude)"    
}

}
```